# ssh can't use key, but password works

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh, permissions, public-key

I have an Ubuntu server running for my SCM, and am doing my development on a windows computer. This setup has worked for a long time with out any problems. But now I get a strange problem.

The problem started when I needed to change the access rights on a git repository on the server (don't tell me it was stupid to `chmod` the entire home directory... I already know). After that, every time I try to access the server via ssh (git inclusive) using my public key. I get the following error:

```
$ ssh git@192.168.0.240
open log failed: Permission denied
Connection to 192.168.0.240 closed.
```

However, when I try to connect to the server, using only password, everything works as expected:

I have tried running the sshcommand with -vvv. It does not give me any idea where to look for the problem. Maybe you can see something from it.

```
...
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 0
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 35
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf_empty delayed efd 6/(35)
open log failed: Permission denied
debug2: channel 0: written 35 to efd 6
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cfd -1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ps. I have also tested this from another computer with same setup, and with the same result.

Comment: 2 questions: 1. Does your `authorized_keys` have some sort of forced command defined? 2. Check `auth.log`. Does the initial login work?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably that the permissions of your user key are wrong. Try this on the Ubuntu server:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, `ssh` also checks the permissions on `~`, which does not be writeable by anybody than the owner (also not via ACL).

Comment: @mpy are you sure? That seems strange, I shold be able to choose to have my home writeable by other users on my network when collaborating. It seems a bit excessive that ssh should require that.

Comment: Quite right, that's common sense. However I learned it the hard way... but as I said, concerning the fine details I wasn't sure anymore. It needed some fiddling, but I could reproduce it again. To benefit from code indention I'll make another answer out of it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [terdons's answer](https://superuser.com/a/562303/195224), some weired behavior with ssh keys also occurs, if `~` is writeable by others.

Assume, you have successfully set up ssh to use key login:

```
user@local:~> ssh remote
Last login: Thu Mar  7 17:39:18 2013 from local
user@remote:~>
```

Now make your home writable by some other user on the *remote* machine:

```
user@remote:~> getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: user
# group: users
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
user@remote:~> setfacl -m u:coauthor:rwx .
user@remote:~> exit
user@local:~>
```

Ok, now try again to log into remote:

```
user@local:~> ssh remote
user@remote's password:
```

`ssh` prompts for password now! Remove the ACL, and voilà ssh key is working again.

[ My workaround was then to use a subdirectory for collaboration.]

---

Craig Sanders knows [the reason](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46757/33390), this behavior depends on `StrictModes yes` in sshd_config. Quoting `man 5 sshd_config`:

> **StrictModes**
>   Specifies whether sshd(8) should check file modes and ownership of the user's files and home directory before accepting
>   login.  This
>                is normally desirable because novices sometimes accidentally leave their directory or files world-writable.  The
>   default is “yes”.

Comment: @terdon: That took me quite some time to identify the reason back then.

Comment: Now it's working again. Thanks all.

The solution was due to access rights of a library (but the .gitolite library). I changed it to `750`.

Comment: @user49884 could you post your solution as an answer please?

Comment: @mpy wow, even writeable by one other user breaks it? Good to know.